Tag purpose: forgery
There are 45 questions tagged forgery; nearly all of them are also tagged either mac, signature, or authenticated-encryption, or tagged with a specific scheme like elgamal-signature—see search for exceptions.
The standard security property of MACs and signatures is unforgeability under chosen-message attack, which is entailed by authenticated encryption, so the concept of ‘forgery’ is implied by the alternative tags.
What purpose does the forgery tag serve?  Should we delete it?

Perhaps you might want to reconsider this sentence: "...every one of which is also tagged either 'mac' or 'signature'."  A quick look at the tags shows that many are not tagged with anything close.  One is simply tagged "forgery". I counted nine which are not tagged with "mac" or "signature" or anything directly related. Then I stopped counting. In point of fact, we see quite a variety of tags used with "forgery". This is not at all to belie the question itself.

You're right; I did the search wrong.

So are the ones not tagged signature or MAC still about signature or MAC or about something different? And if different, are there any questions purely about forgery (this seems unlikely as forgery requires something to be forged) or can we easily apply other tags?

@MaartenBodewes Updated with a clearer search for exceptions.

We should delete forgery in favor of mac and signature.

We should keep forgery because…
Fill me in, Community!

We should keep because not every question on MACs and signatures are about forgery. This can help to search.

Can you expand on that?  For example, show a substantial number of questions that are about MACs or signatures but somehow don't involve forgery?  Expand on why someone would watch a forgery tag but not MAC or signature tags?

Interestingly this nice terminology question has no forgery tag.

There are questions containing HMAC but not about forgery, you will see that if you search secure HMAC that doesn't include forgery tag. This search secure HMAC -[forgery] excludes forgery contains 762 results, but secure HMAC is 762. The intersection is two questions.
Your second point is great, and there is only 1 watcher.

HMAC is a PRF construction, so that's to be expected if the questions are not about its antiforgery properties but rather about its more general pseudorandomness.
